# Find this Question value using range method.

Tags: functions, exponential-function, quadratics

If the range of this function $f(x)$=$\frac{x-A}{x^2-5x+6}$ = R. Then, solve for A .

How can I solve this question.

Comment: What kind of problem you want to solve?

Comment: Is it the range of $f$ that is asked ? Or the max and min of $f$ ?

Comment: What do you call the "normal method" ? By finding the max and min using the derivative ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes. Right . That one.

Comment: @Rider Heyo, from the sound of this question, I am guessing that you are preparing for JEE? You see, stackexchange has people from all around the globe and they won't know the 'words we use unless we explain explicitly. Also, for writing a good question, add an attempt. People appreciate that here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$f_A(x):=\frac{x-A}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{x-A}{(x-2)(x-3)}=R\tag{1}$$

The question is: For a fixed value of $A$, being given value of $R$, can it be reached as image by $f_A$ of a certain **real** value of $x$ ?

Otherwise said, for a fixed value of $A$, what is $f_A(\mathbb{R} \backslash \{2,3\})$ ?

A particular case that can be treated apart: the case where $M=0$ which is evidently reached for any value of $A$ **but** values $A=2$ and $A=3$ (due to simplification by $(x-2)$ or $(x-3)$).

If we plot the curves of $f_A$ for different values of $A$, one sees that there are different cases:

[image]

*Fig. 1: Curves of $y=f_A(x)$. Cases $A<2$ in red; cases $2<A<3$ in black ; cases $A=2$ and $A=3$ in magenta and cyan resp.; cases $A \ge 3$ in blue.*

There is an evident symmetry with respect to point $(2.5;0)$. In order to take profit of this important remark, let us set:

$$g_B(X)=f_A(X+\frac{5}{2})=\dfrac{X-B}{X^2-\tfrac14} \ \text{with} \ B:=A-\tfrac52$$

We have now to find, for a fixed $B$, the range of values of $M$ for which there exists $X$ such that:

$$g_B(X)=\dfrac{X-B}{X^2-\tfrac14} =M \ \ \iff \ \ MX^2-X+(B-\tfrac14M)=0$$

Otherwise said, we have to "discuss", according to the values of $M$ if this quadratic equation has solutions which is equivalent to the fact that its discriminant is $\ge 0$; i.e.,

$$\underbrace{M^2-4MB+1}_{q_B(M)} \ge 0\tag{2}$$

Due to the symmetry of the issue, it is sufficient to consider positive values of $M$.

Let $\delta=4B^2-1$ be the discriminant of $q_B(M)$.

It is known that the sign of such a quadratic expression is

- always $>0$ if $\delta<0$ i.e., if $|B|<1/2$. This means that function $g_B$ is surjective in this case (and only in this case).
- $>0$ if

$$M \ \text{is outside interval} \ [\underbrace{2B-\sqrt{4B^2-1}}_{M_1};\underbrace{2B+\sqrt{4B^2-1}}_{M_2}]$$

where $M_1,M_2$ are the roots of quadratic $q_B$.

It remains to express these conditions in terms of $A$.

Remark: Verification in the case of $B=\frac34 \ \iff A=\frac{13}{4}=3.25$: in this case $[M_1;M_2]=[\tfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2};\tfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}]\approx[0.382;2.618]$ corresponding to the range of values not "covered" by the blue curve above all others in the region $x>3$ of the figure.

Comment: $x=2$ and $x=3$ are plainly the equations of the vertical asymptotes (due to the fact that the denominator $x^2-5x+6=(x-2)(x-3)$ by an immediate computation...). I don't see the direct connection with the range of the function.

Comment: I agree with your answer.

Comment: I have put the Q in edit.

Comment: Sure. I actually solved with your method but my answer was too different than textbook. Maybe it is printing  mistake then

Comment: @JeanMarie $\frac{x+6}{x^2-5x+6} = -20$ has no real solution, so it can't be surjective. Is there an issue I see here?

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon Indeed in this case $A=-6$ represented by the black curve the range (possible domain of values for $R$) is $(0,+\infty)$. $f_{-6}$ isn't surjective. By the way, whatever the value of $A$, none of the functions $f_A$ is surjective. The 'solution" I have given is a first step; a second step is needed for the determination of the range of $R$ given $A$. I haven't done it because the OP, who had begun like me was seeing that the final answer that was given to him/her had nothing to do with a resolution of this type. I will certainly write this second step.

Comment: @JeanMarie Ah, I see! But actually $f_{2.5}$ is surjective , I checked it. I think much, much more clarification with OP is required.

Comment: @Rider What is the answer in your textbook? I want you to edit your question to add some things so that it is not closed for a lack of context. Can you do this?

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon You are perfectly right about the surjectivity. I had made a program error. I rectify the family of curves.

Comment: @JeanMarie No issue, I think I also figured out what the "range" method means, but I'm on the edge of this one because it lacks context as of writing. If OP can fill in some details for me I can write an answer.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon (2,3).

Comment: Now, I understand: it is for values of $A$ belonging to open **interval** $(2,3)$ and only for them that function $f_A$ is surjective (or, with other words, $f_A$ "is onto")

Comment: @JeanMarie K. Thnx a lot.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Kkkk. Thnx